# Issue parsing XLIFF with node XML parser

Tags: node.js, xml, xliff, xml2js

Im trying to parse XLIFF file using xml2js library. All is working fine but if I have something like that: `<source>Welcome to <x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{ title }}"/> my friend</source>` I will get `[{"_":"Welcome to my friend","x":[{"$":{"id":"INTERPOLATION","equiv-text":"{{ title }}"}}]}]`. I am basically loosing order for the parts of the sentence. I would expect to get an array of 3 parts:

```
"Welcome to "
[{"$":{"id":"INTERPOLATION","equiv-text":"{{ title }}"}}]
" my friend"
```

But instead Im getting:

```
"Welcome to my friend"
[{"$":{"id":"INTERPOLATION","equiv-text":"{{ title }}"}}]
```

If I would try to recreate string again I would get `<source>Welcome to my friend<x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{ title }}"/></source>`

Any idea how to solve it with this XML parser or any other?

Comment: Found solution: Im using "sax" parser. You have full control.

Answer (score 1):

you also might like [txml](https://npmjs.com/package/txml). When using it like `txml.parse(yourXMLString)`, you get an object like this:

```json
[
  {
    "tagName": "source",
    "attributes": {},
    "children": [
      "Welcome to ",
      {
        "tagName": "x",
        "attributes": {
          "id": "INTERPOLATION",
          "equiv-text": "{{ title }}"
        },
        "children": []
      },
      " my friend"
    ]
  }
]
```

I think it looks absolutely as what you are looking for. The three children inside the `source`, are very clean to use. Also, this parser is only 4kb in size and there is no need for native c compiling that will cause difficulties when running your app on a different architecture.

Disclaimer: I am the author of txml, and this opinion might not be objective ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With **fast-xml-parser**.
Please, use stopNodes in options when you parse the source.
It makes fast-xml to treat the content as plain-strings

```
var parser = require("fast-xml-parser");
parser.parse(srcFile, {ignoreAttributes: false, stopNodes: ["source", "target"],});
```